# Android emlator size problem

Tags: android-emulator

My Emulator is bigger than my screen.i tried to resize emulator size bt could not do it.
plz help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If starting from the command line you can add the switch "-scale 0.75" to scale the UI 75%. You can also use "-scale 96dpi" to get an interface that's pretty close to the actual size of a phone on most monitors.

If using Eclipse, you should be able to add the -scale switch as an additional emulator option, but it doesn't work. Try creating the AVD using a screen resolution of HVGA. This will fit on a 1024x768 monitor without problems.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the size of the Android Emulator from Eclipse, from the menu bar choose:

1. Run --> Run Configurations
2. Choose the "Target" tab and scroll down to the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" box
3. In that box, you can put "-scale 0.75" or "-scale 96dpi"